# How to update Dictionary if it contains item with same key using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have next function:

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> FromCookies(HttpCookieCollection cc)
{
return (from string cookie in cc.AllKeys select new { Name = cookie, Value = (object)cc[cookie] }).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Name, kvp => kvp.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

But when I build, compiler says me:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

But I need to rewrite this item. How can I do this using LINQ? I'm sorry for my stupid question and if it is so easy to answer.

Comment: You can start by clearly specifying what you want to happen when two cookies have the same name.

Comment: @Jon exactly, this isn't as simple as pulling out all the non-duplicate keys.

Comment: @LewsTherin I work in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: @Jon I want to replace my old cookie value by the new one.

Comment: @matterai: Which one is the new one? Is "cookie" or "cookIE" newer?

Comment: @matterai: Lewis is surprised because that should be a runtime error, not something your compiler warns you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use an IEnumerable of KeyValuePairs, which would allow for multiple items with the same key. You don't lose any data that way:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> FromCookies(HttpCookieCollection cc)
        {
            return (from string cookie in cc.AllKeys select new KeyValuePair<string,object>(cookie, cc[cookie]));
        }
```

Comment: I've done it. But I used foreach. And I checked in every loop if Dictionary contains equals KeyValuePair. So if it contains, I replace it by the new one.

Comment: Fair enough, if you just want to dispose of repeats :-) Worth remembering though that Dictionary<T1,T2> actually implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>, so the Dictionary is more restrictive. You might also want to have a glance at Lookup: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) Not so good if you want to modify a cached copy though...

Answer (score 1):

I might err, but I don't think you can do this using LINQ.
The return statement creates a new dictionary which will be created from the objects within the cookie collection. If this collection contains multiple objects with the same name you've got a problem.

I think the best way to achieve this would be to iterate through the cookie collection, create objects for the dictionary manually and just set them in the dictionary by using the indexer syntax:

```
dictionary[cookiename] = cookieValue;
```

Cheers!

Alex

Comment: This can be done using LINQ, the OP just needs to be more specific in what they want to happen if there are duplicates.

Comment: "But I need to rewrite this item." -> sounds like the OP wants to replace the former object.

Answer (score 0):

You can select *distinct* cookies to avoid duplicate dictionary keys. But, of course you will have only one value in result dictionary. I.e. if you have cookies like `"Hello"`, `"hello"`, and `"HELLO"` - there is no way to put all these keys if you are using ignore case comparison for them. Solution below selects only first of values which are equal with ignored case (i.e. only `"Hello"` key will be added in this case):

```
return (from string cookie in cc.AllKeys.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // here
        select new { 
            Name = cookie, 
            Value = (object)cc[cookie] 
        })
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Name, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

BTW code can be simplified to

```
return cc.AllKeys // use .Cast<string>() if need
         .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
         .ToDictionary(cookie => cookie,
                       cookie => (object)cc[cookie]);
```

Thus you will avoid anonymous objects creation.

Comment: How is this going to work? What happens with cookies with the same keys and different values? I am on the verge of downvoting because this is may or may not work as the OP wants, it obviously still has issues and yet there was no attempt to get clarification.

Comment: @Jon OP retrieving values by `cc[cookie]` so values will be also same

Comment: "Hello" and "hello" will break this if they both exist in the dictionary.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans agree, but there is no way to put both in the dictionary which uses invariant case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have duplicate names, you can use `GroupBy` with the same `StringComparer` first:

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> FromCookies(HttpCookieCollection cc)
{
    var result = cc.AllKeys
        .Select(cookie => new { Name = cookie, Value = (object)cc[cookie] })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return result;
}
```

I'm taking the first value out of the duplicates. But you can change the logic.